# Using PHP to receive a file from the network and save it

Tags: php, networking

I am trying to find out how to create an app in PHP with which I could receive a file from the network and save on my machine. To give the context, this file is sent to my web server (which is set up) from an iPhone app that I developed. I know nothing about PHP, and would appreciate any guidance on how to go about doing that.

To reiterate - all I need is an app that will receive this file and save it on my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply POST the file to your script, and you will be able to find its information in the `$_FILES` super-global variable.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Also, keep in mind that dealing with files can be dangerous if you aren't careful.  You should read up on the security implications before putting files in random places.  Avoid putting them in the web root for sure.

Comment: +1 thanks @Brad. this is great. I am just trying to find an example of such a script since I know literally NOTHING about PHP...thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how do you intend to transfer the files from the iPhone app but perhaps these links might help:

- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Other possible way might be to send the file via email but I'm not sure if the iPhone app can be modified or already provides the feature.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Abhay, but email wont work. Those links are great though!